# How to get the maintainability index?

Tags: code-metrics, ndepend, cql

How can I create the maintainability index with cql?
Does the NDepend calculate this number?

Thanks!

Alejandra

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about CQL.   SD's C# Metrics tool calculate the SEI Maintainability index directly.  See
[C# Metrics Tool](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Metrics/CSharpMetrics.html).